# Piecewise-defined function badly colored

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

I would like to plot this

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}% <- set a compat!! (current version is 1.14)
%%%%%%%
\pgfkeys{/pgf/declare function={argsinh(\x) = ln(\x + sqrt(\x^2+1));}}
\pgfkeys{/pgf/declare function={argcosh(\x) = ln(x + sqrt(-1 + x)*sqrt(1 + x));}}
%%%%%%
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[   
    cycle list name= color list,    
    tick align=center,
    axis lines = left,
    xmin = 0,
    xmax = 2,
    ymin = 0,
    ymax = 1.1,   
    ylabel = {$\mathopen|H(j\Omega)\mathclose|$},    
    xtick = {1,1.2},
    xticklabels = {1, $\Omega_s$},
    ytick = {0,0.1, 0.5, 1},
    yticklabels = {0, $\frac{1}{1+\varepsilon^2/k_1^2}$,$\frac{1}{1+\varepsilon^2}$,1},  
    ]

    \foreach \n in {5,6} {
    \addplot+[domain=0:1,samples=201]{1/(1+1^2*(cos(\n*(acos(\x))))^(2))};

   \addplot+[domain=1:2,samples=201]{1/(1+1^2*(cosh(\n*(argcosh(\x))))^(2))};
    }

    \addplot[black,dotted] coordinates {
        (1.2,1)
        (1.2,.1)
        (2,.1)
    };
    \addplot[black,dotted] coordinates {
        (0,.5)
        (1,.5)
        (1,0)
    };
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

But I have to avoid these four colors and use just two for both \n. Then I realised, it can be done by defining new single piecewise function

```
%%%%%%
\begin{tikzpicture}[
\declare function={
chebyshev(\x)= (\x<=1) * (1/(1+1^2*(cos(\n*(acos(\x))))^(2)))+
     and(\x>1) * (1/(1+1^2*(cosh(\n*(argcosh(\x))))^(2)));
     }]
%%%%%% ...

\foreach \n in {5,6} {

    \addplot+[domain=0:2,samples=400]{chebyshev(\x)};

}
```

But it ends up with error each time and I simply can't see where the problem is. Can you help me?

Comment: Just remove the `+` from `\addplot+` to obtain the same colour for both plots.

Comment: It still doesn't work: Package pgfkeys Error: I do not know the key '/tikz/function', to which you p
assed ' chebyshev(\x )= (\x <=1) * (1/(1+1^2*(cos(\n *(acos(\x ))))^(2)))+ and(
\x >1) * (1/(1+1^2*(cosh(\n *(argcosh(\x ))))^(2))); ', and I am going to ignor
e it. Perhaps you misspelled it.

Comment: I mean in your first try, without the piecewise function.

Comment: Also it is `declare function` without a `\ `.

Comment: But I need different colors for them so that anyone can clearly distinguish the order \n

Comment: Ok, I removed \ , but now it says:

! Package PGF Math Error: Sorry, an internal routine of the floating point unit
got an ill-formatted floating point number `Y'. The unreadable part was near '
Y'. (in '(0Y0.0e0]<=1)*(1/(1+1^2*(cos(5*(acos(0Y0.0e0]))))^(2)))+and(0Y0.0e0]>1
)*(1/(1+1^2*(cosh(5*(argcosh(0Y0.0e0]))))^(2)))').

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that `acos(x)` is only defined for `x \in [0,1]` and you are trying to plot for `x \in [0,2]`.  The easiest thing to do would be to stick with the two function variant and back up the colour index by one before plotting the second using `\pgfplotsset{cycle list shift=-1}`.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}% <- set a compat!! (current version is 1.14)
%%%%%%% 
\pgfkeys{/pgf/declare function={argsinh(\x) = ln(\x + sqrt(\x^2+1));}}
\pgfkeys{/pgf/declare function={argcosh(\x) = ln(x + sqrt(-1 + x)*sqrt(1 + x));}}
%%%%%% 
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}[   
    cycle list name= color list,    
    tick align=center,
    axis lines = left,
    xmin = 0,
    xmax = 2,
    ymin = 0,
    ymax = 1.1,   
    ylabel = {$\mathopen|H(j\Omega)\mathclose|$},    
    xtick = {1,1.2},
    xticklabels = {1, $\Omega_s$},
    ytick = {0,0.1, 0.5, 1},
    yticklabels = {0, $\frac{1}{1+\varepsilon^2/k_1^2}$,$\frac{1}{1+\varepsilon^2}$,1},  
    ]

    \foreach \n in {5,6} {
      \addplot+[domain=0:1,samples=201]{1/(1+1^2*(cos(\n*(acos(\x))))^(2))};
      \pgfplotsset{cycle list shift=-1}
      \addplot+[domain=1:2,samples=201]{1/(1+1^2*(cosh(\n*(argcosh(\x))))^(2))};
    }

    \addplot[black,dotted] coordinates {
      (1.2,1)
      (1.2,.1)
      (2,.1)
    };
    \addplot[black,dotted] coordinates {
      (0,.5)
      (1,.5)
      (1,0)
    };
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you! For the trees I did not see the forest. Now it's clear.

Comment: What about legend entries? How to tackle with them?